# Change Owner of folder

Tags: permissions

My username is murali and am also su

Used Testdisk and recovered files are in a subfolder of .Trash-1000 folder in Home directory
.Trash-1000 has a lock sign and permissions of both the folder and contents indicate owner is root. Can't access these files.

Used sudo chown -R $murali: .Trash-1000
But folder and files still remain locked.
If I leave out space    ie $murali:.Trash-1000, then I can get response "Missing operand after .Trash-1000"

Made myself as rootuser by ... sudo -i    command.
Still cannot access files.

How can I access these files, copy them, view them or modify them.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.Trash-1000` file is for *your* user account, then you can access the files from the Nautilus file manager by clicking on the "Rubbish Bin":

[image: Nautilus Rubbish Bin]

If you would like to use the command line to examine the contents of the `.trash-1000` file — assuming you are the owner of the file — then you can use the `gio` commands:

```
gio list trash://
```

You can then use `gio move` to relocate deleted files. The `gio` commands [are documented here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html).

If the directory is *not* yours and you need to gain ownership, you can use:

```
sudo chown -R murali:murali .Trash-1000
```

The file permissions should also be set to `700`, as only the owner should have access:

```
sudo chmod -R 700 .Trash-1000
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.